# second else if stament is NOT working properly

Tags: bash, if-statement

My second "else if" is not working. I cannot download the file if the file is not there. I do not know what I'm doing wrong here.

```
#!/bin/bash
# upper case
file_upper_case=/root/MASTER.txt
# lower case
file_lower_case=/root/master.txt

if [ -e "$file_upper_case" ]; then
    echo "File is upper-case"
    echo "Changed to lower_case"
    mv $file_upper_case $file_lower_case
    chmod 664 $file_lower_case
    chown root.dba $file_lower_case

else if [ -e "$file_lower_case" ]; then
    echo "File is lower_case"
    echo "Change permission only"
    chmod 664 $file_lower_case
    chmod root.dba $file_lower_case

else if [ -e "$file_lower_case"]; then
    echo "File does not exist"
    echo "Create master.txt file"
   # Download master.txt file
    wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/userid/bin/raw/master.txt -P /root
    chmod 664 /root/master.txt
    chown root.dba /root/master.txt
fi; fi
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same condition as the first else if? I'm not sure how smart bash is, but it's possible that it might not run after the first one is found.

Comment: `"];` gives some problems as well. Should be `" ];`

Comment: Were you thinking about `else if [ ! -e "$file_lower_case"]; then`? (Note the `!`)

Comment: I use elif and is not working. CargoMeister, I did not realize my mistake having the same condition, what can I use the instead.!! thank you both of you of your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want this *(tested)*:

```
#!/bin/bash

file_upper_case=/root/MASTER.txt
file_lower_case=/root/master.txt

if [ -e "$file_upper_case" ]; then
    echo "File is upper-case"
    echo "Changed to lower_case"
    mv $file_upper_case $file_lower_case
    chmod 664 $file_lower_case
    chown root.dba $file_lower_case
elif [ -e "$file_lower_case" ]; then
    echo "File is lower_case"
    echo "Change permission only"
    chmod 664 $file_lower_case
    chmod root.dba $file_lower_case
else
    echo "File does not exist"
    echo "Create master.txt file"
    # Download master.txt file
    wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/userid/bin/raw/master.txt -P /root
    chmod 664 /root/master.txt
    chown root.dba /root/master.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `elif` instead of `else if`. Moreover you missed a space in the last if condition.